# In the GSC page indexing issues: Found a URL with a two different file names

Tags: seo, redirects, search-engine-indexing, technical-seo

Strange URLs in Search Console's Page with a redirect, Alternate page with Proper Canonical  Tag'

Search Console is showing 240 excluded pages with 'Page with a redirect, Alternate Page with Proper Canonical Tag etc'. The URLs are something like this and it is almost found in all the errors.

https://www.syoft.com/mobile-app-development.php/devops.php
(Not the target page, but it's still under excluded list hence I wanted to fix)

The above page has two different file names if you observe `/mobile-app-development.php` and `/devops.php`

These all appeared as I launched a site rebuild. I'm concerned it's something to do with my 301 redirects in the `.htaccess` file or Is this the reason some of my pages are not indexed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a commented-out link to /devops.php on your /services/mobile-app-development.php. If this was live, search engines would follow the link, which would result in the strange URLs you see.

Even commented out, Google may decide to check it out anyhow.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong, /devops.php would result in a different wrong page. If you had a link for "devops.php" with no slash, the URLs you see would happen.